# Arduino PID relay output with ds1820 not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, arduino, pid-controller

I'm attempting to use a ds1820 temperature probe with the PID library for relay output. I'm getting the temperature just fine from the probe, but I'd expect the relay output, in this case just print statements for on/off, to change when the temperature is above the setpoint. They do not. Perhaps I have missed something, but I thought it would be useful to have another set of eyes on this, as it is pretty much verbatim to the PID library example code, with a modification to take the Input from the ds1820, and likely very useful to others. In this example, the setpoint is 60. I'd expect the print statement to be on while the temperature is below 60, and off while the temperature is above. What I get is "on" if the temperature is below 60, and still "on" if the temperature rises above 60.

```
/*-----( Import needed libraries )-----*/
// Get 1-wire Library here: http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OneWire.html
#include <OneWire.h>
//Get DallasTemperature Library here:  http://milesburton.com/Main_Page?title=Dallas_Temperature_Control_Library
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <PID_v1.h>
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS_PIN 3

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS_PIN);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DeviceAddress Probe01 = { 0x28, 0x92, 0xBA, 0xAF, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0xD1 }; //x1

//Define Variables we'll be connecting to
double pidInputTemp;
double Setpoint, Input, Output;

//Specify the links and initial tuning parameters
double Kp=2, Ki=5, Kd=1;
PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &Setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);

int WindowSize = 5000;
unsigned long windowStartTime;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200);
  sensors.begin();
  // set the resolution of the ds1820s to 12 bit (Can be 9 to 12 bits .. lower is faster)
  sensors.setResolution(Probe01, 12);
  windowStartTime = millis();

  //initialize the variables we're linked to
  Setpoint = 60;

  //tell the PID to range between 0 and the full window size
  myPID.SetOutputLimits(0, WindowSize);

  //turn the PID on
  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
}

void loop()
{
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 
  theTemperature(Probe01);
  myPID.Compute();

  /************************************************
   * turn the output pin on/off based on pid output
   ************************************************/
  if(millis() - windowStartTime>WindowSize)
  { //time to shift the Relay Window
    windowStartTime += WindowSize;
  }
  if(Output < millis() - windowStartTime) Serial.println("On");
  else Serial.println("Off");

}
void theTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
   if (tempC == -127.00) 
   {
   Serial.println("Error getting temperature  ");
   } 
   else
   {
   float tempF = (DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC));
   Serial.println("Setpoint: ");
   Serial.println(Setpoint);
   Serial.println("Now: ");
   Serial.println(tempF);
   Input = tempF;
   }
}
```

Comment: In looking at the original code, the Input is reading analog. (0-255), and not a temperature. Makes sense for a wide range of applications, but not a strict temperature. I suppose converting the temperature to analog might work, but is a bit tricky. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a resource which appears to do what I want, albeit with a lot of bloat for a LCD screen and buttons. Adafruit has a more robust PID with interrupt, EPROM write/call for parameters, and autotune up at https://learn.adafruit.com/sous-vide-powered-by-arduino-the-sous-viduino/the-whole-enchilada -- I need to strip down a lot of the code, as I'm not using a LCD and would rather have the buttons replaced with serial commands.